# tell jaxb to not remove underscores

Tags: java, xml, naming-conventions, jaxb

Is there a way to tell JAXB to not remove underscores when creating getter/setter names from XML Schema?
Reason: this causes loss of information and it is harder to trip between XML and Java; e.g. in written communications where one participant might be confused about "different names".

Example: NR_ROR should not become getNRROR but getNR_ROR.

Note: I believe that the less-mangled names are worth the "violation" of Java naming convention.
TIA
karolrvn

Comment: just curious, what's so wrong with nrRor and getNrRor?

Comment: For one, it just isn't the "same thing" for someone who knows the names in the XML.

Comment: If the names are to symbolize the same thing. They should be the same. Otherwise there would be naming roundtrips (e.g. for searching corresponding element in schema/XML you would have to re-mangle the names) and possible confusion. NrRor is short so it could be written by hand but there are longer and more tricky names.

Comment: For example KWOTA_DO_ZAPLATY_SL became, (drums) getKWOTADOZAPLATYSL() . Had it become getKwotaDoZaplatySl(), it would be better but still annoying. I wrote my entire program calling methods with mangled names like that. But I would like to improve this in my next program.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a custom binding and set "underscoreBinding" to "asCharInWord".  One approach is to create a file called binding.xjb and use the -b flag to tell xjc where it is.  Here's an example of what you'd put in binding.xml:

```
<jaxb:bindings
   xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   version="1.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="foobar.xsd">
      <jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the underscoreBinding that jaxb provides. See, for example, in the docs here -> http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

I have never used it since I like camelCaseWords, but it sounds like it does what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answer.<br/>
Maybe enableJavaNamingConventions = false ?<br/>
However I didn't find any description of this

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for how to do the same thing, with the additional qualification that the schema is embedded inside a WSDL. To do that, combine https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545815/4512591 with lreeder's answer above, changing:

```
schemaLocation="foobar.xsd"
```

to

```
wsdlLocation="foobar.wsdl"
```

Net result:

```
<jaxb:bindings
   xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   version="1.0">
   <jaxb:bindings wsdlLocation="foobar.wsdl">
      <jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This is with the JAXWS Reference Implementation, at least.

Comment: wsdlLocation is not valid for jaxb:bindings and using jaxws:bindings does not help either