# How to debug Wsdl2Java Jaxb error "declarations cause a collision"

Tags: jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a wsdl that was generated by .NET that I am trying to consume in a java application.  To do this, I am trying to use the CXF Wsdl2Java tool.  The problem is that when the tool runs, it throws a jaxb exception:

```
Thrown by JAXB: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
```

I understand that I probably need to create a custom binding file to rename an object at build time, but I have no idea where to start.  How do I find out which objects in the wsdl are causing the problems?

(It seems like it would be *nice* if the exception actually said which elements were causing the naming conflict)

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

1. tell cxf to resolve name collision with : -autoNameResolution
   command line argument
2. [tell jaxb to not remove underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146742/388038) with :
   jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"

Comment: Source URL is not available any more... :(

Comment: @predrags sorry, it's a rather old answer and it's not on Web Archive. The options for cxf are documented here https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

For the jaxb customization https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148515

An example for customizing this underscoreBinding https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146742/388038

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, make sure you are using the latest version of CXF's wsdl2java tool.   The latest versions have done a better job of trying to get the line/col numbers of where JAXB is finding these types of errors.   That at least can give a basic indication of where to look, but they still aren't easy to track down.