# How to create and include Java classes and multiple WSDLs for a jar

Tags: maven, wsimport

I'm generating java classes from multiple wsdl files. Works. However, I want to provide the appropriate wsdl file in the @WebServiceClient annotation. In the attribute wsdlLocation I expect the directory path concatenated with the distinct file name. E.g. /myDir/myWsdl-1.wsdl for the first webservice.  However, the wsdlLocation is populated with "/myDir" only - without the service name. How do I supply that name for each wsdl?

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "myService", targetNamespace = "http://mycompany.com/services/", wsdlLocation = "/myDir")
```

Below is my instruction:

```
<wsdlLocation>/myDir</wsdlLocation>
<wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/myDir</wsdlDirectory>
<wsdlFiles>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-3.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-4.wsdl</wsdlFile>
</wsdlFiles>
```

What slips my attention?

Thanks for any hints. Feder.

Comment: Adding /* to the wsdLocation value doesn't help neither. `It reports External binding file(s) can not be bound to more WSDL files (/myDir/*)Please use either inline binding(s) or multiple execution tags.`

Answer (score 8):

Ok. One may use the path followed by a slash and an asterisk in order to generate classes for mutlitple WSDL files. E.g.

```
<wsdlLocation>/myDir/*</wsdlLocation>
```

However, in this case, you cannot apply a binding.

```
<bindingDirectory>src/main/binding</bindingDirectory>
```

If you need to apply a binding for each of the WSDLs, then you must repeat the execution block of the plugin or apply a wsdl-inline-binding. See this [discussion for inline-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535656/how-to-customize-the-schema-inlined-inside-an-imported-wsdl).

Hope this helps others, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `<wsdlFiles>` element enclosing list of `<wsdlFile>` elements. It should be like this:

```
<wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/myDir</wsdlDirectory>
<wsdlFiles>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-3.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>myWsdl-4.wsdl</wsdlFile>
</wsdlFiles>
```

Comment: Example how to use `<wsdlLocation>` can be found here: https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#wsdlLocation